# where is permalink info stored in database?

Tags: permalinks, database

I see that I can edit permalink information in wp-admin page > settings > permalinks. However, where is that information actually stored in the database?

Answer (score 16):

In the `wp_options` table there is a record where `option_name = "permalink_structure"`.

However, the true, ultimate control of url rewriting is controlled by the [WP_Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) which saves/caches its information in the `rewrite_rules` wordpress option (also found in the `wp_options` table).

EDIT:

Also, when editing a page/post, you can change the "permalink" for that page/post (right below where you change the title). All that is doing is merely setting the `post_name` field for that page's/post's entry in `wp_posts` table (aka it's changing the "slug" for that page).

For all pages, it seems that the default rewrite rules are the following:

```
[(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
[(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

That list was obtained by me running this php code: `echo nl2br('rules = '.print_r( $wp_rewrite->rules, true) . "\n");`

There does not seem to be any builtin way to edit routing for pages since the permalink structure only applies to posts.

EDIT:

More random information I'm discovering: if your permalink_structure is an empty string (which is the "default" option you can choose), then wordpress completely skips all rewriting -- I'm really not sure why that's the case, but it is.

Answer (score 13):

The actual information - e.g. the 'slug' for the page or post is stored in wp_posts under the post_name column. This is a slugified version of post_title normally, but can be overwritten on a page by page basis.

The full permalink is deconstructed based on what settings you have chosen in Settings -> Permalinks, but the actual slug is in post_name in wp_posts.

Answer (score 0):

Permalink information is stored in wp_options.

Table name :- $wpdb->prefix'options'

And search option name like 'permalink_structure' in option table.

In that row in a table u can view the permalink structure.