# Restore Category Base

Tags: plugins, errors

One hiccup I've noticed with WordPress is that when you use any plugin which removes the category base for posts and turn the plugin off, your posts will now return 404 errors. In addition, WP will continue to remove the category base - even though the plugin is deactivated.

Thus far, I've tested this with two plugins with the same result:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-base/

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "any plugin" is pretty broad. What has this actually been tested with?

Comment: I updated the question to address which plugins this happens with (out of those tested).

Comment: Did you try to re-save your permalinks (Settings » Permalinks) after you've deactivated the plugin?

Comment: Tried that @Sven

Comment: What version of WP are you running? Did you put the plugin in plugins dir or are you using it within your theme?

Comment: Latest version of WP. Deleted the plugins and it was within the plugins directory.

Comment: Have you already attempted the solutions in the [404 related support threads](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-no-category-base) here? One suggesting emptying cache and the other involving renaming your categories then creating new categories with the original name.

Comment: change the permalink on site to defoult and after that, check the site: it will start working again and after that set it again accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was most likely down voted because [the answer is in the plugin support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-no-category-base-404-error-on-page-and-post). As stated by others in the comments, set default permalinks and save settings. Clear cache. Set permalink structure to what you want and save.

Also, feel free to look in the database.

[where is permalink info stored in database?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58625/where-is-permalink-info-stored-in-database)