# Permalink structure has suddenly changed

Tags: permalinks

I've just noticed that the permalink structure on my site has changed, I've tried the usual stuff (flushing permalinks etc) but to no avail.

The original structure was

`mysite.co.uk/blog/some-title`

but it's now become

`mysite.co.uk/some-title`

In a nutshell the 'blog' part of the url has completely disappeared.

I haven't made any changes to the permalink settings, or any of the theme files - does any one have any ideas?

Comment: even if you didn't make changes. did you look on your permalinks page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I sorted it in the end - somehow the word 'blog' had removed itself from /blog/%postname%/ in Custom Structure, possibly on a recent permalinks flush..

Comment: check this :- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58625/where-is-permalink-info-stored-in-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Somehow the word blog had removed itself from /blog/%postname%/ in custom post structure, possibly on a recent permalinks flush..